# Why does MsgBox pop up twice?

Tags: vba, database, ms-access

I am designing one login form for trainers and members.
If a member logs in they are redirected to "frm2_Member Class Registration" form.
If a trainer logs in they are redirected to "frm3_Main Menu" form.

When the login button (Command9_Click) is clicked, the msgbox pops up correctly, but is displayed twice.
When the trainer logs on the msgbox says, Login Successful. Then another msgbox pops up straight away saying "Login failed", however all the data is displayed correctly.
It's just the msgboxes that do not work correctly.

```vb
Private Sub Command9_Click()
    
If (DCount("MemberFirstName", "tbl1_Members", "MemberEmail = [txtEmail] And MemberPassword = [txtPassword] ")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Welcome")
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm1_Member & Trainer Login"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm2_Member Class Registration"
Else
    MsgBox ("Login Failed")
End If
     
If (DCount("TrainerFirstName", "tbl4_Trainers", "TrainerEmail = [txtEmail] And TrainerPassword = [txtPassword] ")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Welcome")
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm1_Member & Trainer Login"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm3_Main Menu"
Else
    MsgBox ("Login Failed")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: use an `ElseIf` instead of the second `If`

Comment: Hi again, I have built a login form for both trainers and members, they can both login into one form. However I would like to make sure when either the trainer or the member logs in, the message box pops up and should say. "Welcome =[FirstName] & " " & [LastName]". So basically after welcome the members or the trainers fullname is displayed.

Can you please help me out, would really appreciate it, Thanks. My code is shown below.

Comment: Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command9_Click()

    Dim isTrainer As Boolean, isMember As Boolean

    isTrainer = DCount("TrainerFirstName", "tbl4_Trainers", _
                 "TrainerEmail = [txtEmail] And TrainerPassword = [txtPassword] ") > 0
    isMember = DCount("MemberFirstName", "tbl1_Members", _
                 "MemberEmail = [txtEmail] And MemberPassword = [txtPassword] ") > 0

Comment: If isTrainer Or isMember Then
        MsgBox ("Welcome & = [TrainerFirstName] & " " & [TrainerLastName] or = [MemberFirstName] & " " & [MemberLastName] ")
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm1_Member & Trainer Login"
        If isTrainer Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frm3_Main Menu"
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frm2_Member Class Registration"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox ("Login Failed")
    End If

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code keeps running after the 1st End If.  It would be better to combine these two separate If statements together using an ElseIf, thereby only generating the failed message when both If statements are untrue.

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()

If (DCount("MemberFirstName", "tbl1_Members", "MemberEmail = [txtEmail] And MemberPassword = [txtPassword] ")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Welcome")
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm1_Member & Trainer Login"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm2_Member Class Registration"
ElseIf (DCount("TrainerFirstName", "tbl4_Trainers", "TrainerEmail = [txtEmail] And TrainerPassword = [txtPassword] ")) > 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Welcome")
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm1_Member & Trainer Login"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frm3_Main Menu"
Else
    MsgBox ("Login Failed")
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Command9_Click()

    Dim isTrainer As Boolean, isMember As Boolean

    isTrainer = DCount("TrainerFirstName", "tbl4_Trainers", _
                 "TrainerEmail = [txtEmail] And TrainerPassword = [txtPassword] ") > 0
    isMember = DCount("MemberFirstName", "tbl1_Members", _
                 "MemberEmail = [txtEmail] And MemberPassword = [txtPassword] ") > 0

    If isTrainer Or isMember Then
        MsgBox ("Welcome")
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frm1_Member & Trainer Login"
        If isTrainer Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frm3_Main Menu"
        Else
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frm2_Member Class Registration"
        End If

    Else
        MsgBox ("Login Failed")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, I am so pleased that you helped me, I am so glad you helped me out Thanks my dear friend.